# SQL Server 2008 - Service account for backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, service-accounts

I am setting up a backup software to backup all the databases on my MS SQL Server 2008.

I want to configure a service account with administrator rights on the database. The service account have already been created in the AD, but has no rights at the moment.

How can I give database rights to my service account so that he will be able to launch backup tasks?

Comment: Did you read the manual for RedGate SQL Backup Pro?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the backup software I am using. I just want to set up a service account for backing up SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\USER] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\USER', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you were using RedGate for this. Though this is a SQL Server configuration issue, [the RedGate documentation](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/knowledgebase/SQL_Backup/KB200710000173) clearly walks you through how to do this.